# How to authenticate user before request?

Tags: spring, security

I’m developing restful api.

I want to authenticate user by using some signature value on every API.

The signature value would be stored on my database. I want to compare signature value from my database and value from user request.

Any hint for this flow?

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to use a mid-length token (32 to 256 characters), passed as a query parameter or in a header.

If you need stronger security, you could pass instead a hash computed from other parameters of the query and that *signature*. That way a distinct value is passed for every request, and the protocol becomes more resistent to Man In The Middle attacks.

You usually end with a balance between simplicity and security (HTTPS can be the protection against MITM). So you should first identify the risks and threats you want to mitigate.

Comment: Any option for make it simple? passed as params needs to be implemented on every request api.

Comment: With Spring framework, you could implement that part in a Filter or a Spring interceptor. That way the busyness class should not even be aware of the security part.

Comment: Which one is more prefer? filter or interceptor? my purpose is authenticate user on every request.

Comment: The Filter interface is defined at Java-ee level and does not depend on Spring Framework. At the opposite, an interceptor is a Spring object and is natively interfaced with Spring containers  and Spring MVC. If you prefere tight Spring (and Spring MVC) integration, choose an interceptor, if you want a solution that can work in a non Spring  MVC environment use a Filter. But this is close to a matter of taste...